# Debug Ionic application with android:debuggable="false"

Tags: android, cordova, debugging, ionic-framework, signed

A have installed my Ionic application on real device. The app is released, signed and has android:debuggable="false".
I faced some problems on that specific device and I need to debug it (not to create and install new --debug build).

Is there some way to debug it? To "attach" it somehow to a keystore to be authorised, or something else...? Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

I am still trying to find a better way, but so far I am able to debug my Ionic app (a *signed* `--release` build) running on a real device via the Chrome (desktop) console, by specifying:

`<application android:debuggable="true">`

directly in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file. The attribute in not overwritten when I build the project with the Ionic CLI.

What I would prefer is to set the attribute from the `config.xml` file, so I don't have to add it again manually in `AndroidManifest.xml` when I remove/add the platform.

Answer (score 5):

You can add this in your config.xml to solve it.

```
<platform name="android">
    <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <application android:debuggable="true" />
    </edit-config>
```

Then, you can debug in Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

I've just faced a similar issue (I wanted to create a debuggable Cordova app with `cordova build android --release`) and I've also wanted to add something to the Cordova `config.xml` instead of directly editing `AndroidManifest.xml`, which is generally a bad idea.

The following piece of code worked for me on Cordova 8.1.2, Cordova Android platform version 7.1.4. Just put this inside your `config.xml` file (somewhere inside the widget tag) and you should be good to go:

```
<config-file mode="merge" parent="/manifest" platform="android" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application android:debuggable="true" />
</config-file>
```

This will also cause the `:app:lintVitalRelease` linter to give you a `[HardcodedDebugMode]` error (and for good reason), but the APK will build fine regardless.